# iOS: Instagram Api throws error message

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, instagram-api

I have integrated Instagram Authentication in my Ionic3.4 App. After successful login, I store User's token and UID from the Authentication response. Next, I make an api call to Instagram Endpoint to get current User's Photos. It works perfectly on Android. But it doesn't work on iOS platform. It throws below error:
[image]

It should load images as in Android:[image]

This is the code I used to fetch photos from Instagram:

**InstagramService.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class InstagramService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }

  getInstagramUserInfo(accessToken) {
    //GET USER PHOTOS
    return this.http
      .get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=' + accessToken)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .map((res: any) => {
        let images: Array<String> = [];
        res.data.forEach(element => {
          images.push(element.images.thumbnail.url);
        });
        return images;
      })
      .catch((error: any) =>
        Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
      );
  }
}
```

**instagram-photos.ts:**

```
getInstagramPhotos(accessToken) {
    this.showLoading();
    this.instagramService.getInstagramUserInfo(accessToken)
        .subscribe((response: Array<string>) => {
            this.images = response;
            this.hideLoading();
        }, (error: any) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            this.hideLoading();
        });
}
```

**instagram-photos.html:**

```
<ion-content padding="true">
    <ion-grid>
        <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index;">
            <ion-row *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
                <ion-col col-4 (click)="openPhoto(image)" *ngIf="i < images.length">
                    <img [src]="images[i]" />
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-4 (click)="openPhoto(image)" *ngIf="i+1 < images.length">
                    <img [src]="images[i+1]" />
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-4 (click)="openPhoto(image)" *ngIf="i+2 < images.length">
                    <img [src]="images[i+2]" />
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </div>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Now, **main.js** looks like below around line number 60951:

[image]

**PS:**

Incase you want to know *ionic info*

$ ionic info

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.10
```

**Edit: 1**

I went ahead debugging application on Safari, I found this issue with making that api call:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Can anyone suggest the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution for this. Instagram API supports JSONP, so I made jsonp call instead of http call when device is iOS. I achieved this as below:
Firstly, in **app.module.ts**, import **JsonpModule** as:

```
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Then, add **JsonpModule** in imports array as:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [...]
})
```

Finally, I made a check that if platform is `android` then make normal `Http` call and if platform is `ios` then make `Jsonp` call. Thats it...!!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Jsonp } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";

@Injectable()
export class InstagramService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private jsonp: Jsonp, private platform: Platform) {

  }

  getInstagramUserInfo(accessToken) {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      return this.http
        .get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=' + accessToken, {})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .map((res: any) => {
          let images: Array<String> = [];
          res.data.forEach(element => {
            images.push(element.images.thumbnail.url);
          });
          return images;
        })
        .catch((error: any) =>
          Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
        );
    } else {
      return this.jsonp
        .get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=' + accessToken + "&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK", {})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .map((res: any) => {
          let images: Array<String> = [];
          res.data.forEach(element => {
            images.push(element.images.thumbnail.url);
          });
          return images;
        })
        .catch((error: any) =>
          Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
        );
    }
  }
}
```